# Moving labels in QGIS is stuck

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have vector layer on QGIS 3.8 that contains different polygons, each one is labeled by its' name. I have used the label toolbar to move the labels, and it worked for one of the layers I have, but then on the next ones it got stuck and I can't move the labels.
I have chose the correct field so this is not the problem.
Any idea what else can make this not functioning?

Comment: The auxiliary table that stores position coordinates for the label of each feature must be correctly joined to the layer. They must have a common field with unique values, and must be already joined. Also, the position coordinate fields of the auxiliary table must be included in both (X and Y) expressions of the *Data defined* placement of the label. Please include in the question: - the *Source Fields* tab; - the *Auxiliary Storage* tab; - and the *Placement* section of the *Labels* tab; of the layer properties.

Comment: Hi, The labels are coming from the layer, it's not a different table, if that what you meant. How can I get acess to the auxiliary table?